# Rsync folder time and date

Tags: rsync

I'm using `rsync` to copy and noticed that the destination folders have the current time and date. Not the time and date of the source. Did I miss a switch in my command?

```
nohup rsync -avhP /c/Media/Movies/ /USB_HDD_24/Movies/ &

-a Archive
-v Verbose
-h human
-P Progress
```

I believe the -a should include

```
-o = owner 
-g = group
-t = time
```

Comment: There is a `--omit-dir-times` option to not copy directory times, whilst still keeping file times.

Comment: What filesystem type is your target using?

Comment: Were the dates wrong *during* the transfer, or *after* the transfer completed.

Answer (score 0):

-a (archive) should do what you want.

however, -t (preserve modification times) is the specific command to do it.